# Is it possible to choose JavaScript runtime environment (rhino...etc) when sourcing a JavaScript file in html?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

Is it possible to choose JavaScript runtime environment (rhino...etc) when sourcing a JavaScript file in html ??

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<script src="file_1.js"></script>
  <script src="file_2.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">

 <title></title>

</head>
<body>

 <p id="test">abc</p>
</body>
```

file_1.js:

```
window.paragraph = readFile('file_to_read.tcl'); 
localStorage.setItem("paragraph", paragraph);
```

file_2.js:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = window.paragraph;

 }, 3000);
```

need to read the "file_to_read.tcl" and then pass the "paragraph" variable to the second js file "file_2.js"

but still finding this issue : "ReferenceError: readFile is not defined"

thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you mean here, do you want to force your website users to use Rhino, then the answer is NO.

Comment: I have a readFile function in a js script which instantiated in html, but shown not defined when running the html in the browser, so i asked if i can for example force the script to be run with rhino as the "readFile" function is known there

Comment: What do you mean `instancianted in html`? Could we see the code?

Comment: Are you wanting to read files directly on users PC, you can't.  It's a security restriction.  You can send files though, via the INPUT type file.

Comment: Isn't Rhino a JS runtime, like Node.js ? So that's server-side, right? But the code above is HTML, so I have no idea what's happening here :o)

Comment: the code is above

Comment: It seems you have a html file. Now you're asking if you can choose which browser it must be viewed with? No, you can't. And no, there's no browser using the rhino runtime.

Comment: ok , but is there any solution to fix  the issue above (related to readFile which is shown not defined ??)

Comment: You can't access filesystem with javascript running on a browser.